# HP Envy Fingerprint scanner in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, fingerprint-reader

Just bought an HP Envy 14-j122TX machine and installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

`lsusb` tells me there is a Swipe Fingerprint Sensor:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 138a:0050 Validity Sensors, Inc. Swipe Fingerprint Sensor
```

Tried `fingerprint-gui` and also `fprintd-enroll`, neither can go any further.

Any help on this?